# How to override an abstract inner class of an abstract class in their subclasses (kotlin or java)

Tags: java, kotlin, subclass, abstract, inner-classes

So basically I have a abstract class representing a BinaryTree below. I want to create a subclass called RBTree which will take advantage of all the abstraction in BinaryTree including the ability to modify the inner Node class to take on a color and parent property.

However I can't figure out how Kotlin or Java do this if they can even at all.

The closest I'm able to come is creating a new class that's a subclass of Node which ruins a lot of the other abstraction in BinaryTree since we have to use different Node objects. Trying to just redefine Node just doesn't work. If you know how to do it in java that would work too.

```
class RBTree<E : Comparable<E>> : BinaryTree<E>(){
    override val rootNode: RBNode<E> = TODO()

    override fun addNode(node: Node<E>) { //since we have a new class RBNode this doesn't work
        TODO()
    }
    override fun removeNode(): Node<E> { //same problem
        TODO()
    }

    inner class RBNode<E>(data: E, var color: NodeColor, var parent: RBNode<E>?, left: RBNode<E>? = null, right: RBNode<E>? = null) : Node<E>(data, left, right){
        fun switchColor() : NodeColor{
            color = when (color) {
                NodeColor.RED -> NodeColor.BLACK
                else -> NodeColor.RED
            }
            return color
        }
    }

}

enum class NodeColor {
    RED,
    BLACK
}
```

```
abstract class BinaryTree<E : Comparable<E>>() {

    abstract val rootNode: Node<E>

    abstract fun addNode(node : Node<E>)

    abstract fun removeNode() : Node<E>

    abstract inner class Node<E : Comparable<E>>(
        private val data: E,
        private val left: Node<E>? = null,
        private val right: Node<E>? = null) : Comparable<Node<E>> {

        fun isLeaf(): Boolean{
            return (left == null && right == null)
        }
        override fun compareTo(other: Node<E>): Int {
            return data.compareTo(other.data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in the way you want.  It will take more complex generics, like having `<N: Node<E>>` and the like.

Comment: The Node inner class as designed doesn't look like it needs to be marked `inner` since it's not accessing any outer class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a limitation of Java or Kotlin. This case is tricky even conceptually. Let's think about it for a while.

We have a common "family" of objects. Then we have a more specialized family which accepts working with their own family only. `RBTree` doesn't accept working with just any `Node`, it requires `RBNode` specifically, for example in `addNode()`. That means `RBTree` effectively **is not** a subtype of `BinaryTree`, because it can't be used as a `BinaryTree`.

There are multiple ways to tackle this problem, depending on our specific case.

If we construct the whole graph initially and then we only work with it, but we don't mutate it anymore, then we can separate read-only and mutable interfaces. Only this initial code for constructing the graph will have to make sure `RBTree` correctly got `RBNode`. Then `RBTree` can be safely treated as a read-only `BinaryTree` and depending if we use `RBTree` or `BinaryTree`, we see nodes as either `RBNode` or `Node`.

Another approach, very specific to some cases is to adapt `Node` to be the `RBNode`. In this solution `RBTree` allows to add regular `Node` objects to it, but it wraps them in its own classes and when asked back, it returns a wrapped `RBNode`. This approach also allows `RBTree` to be a subtype of the `BinaryTree`.

Third solution is to parameterize the tree by its node type. We have to introduce `N : Node<N, E>` in multiple places around the code:

```kotlin
class RBTree<E : Comparable<E>> : BinaryTree<RBNode<E>, E>(){
    override val rootNode: RBNode<E> = TODO()

    override fun addNode(node: RBNode<E>) {
        TODO()
    }
    override fun removeNode(): RBNode<E> {
        TODO()
    }

    class RBNode<E : Comparable<E>>(data: E, var color: NodeColor, var parent: RBNode<E>?, left: RBNode<E>? = null, right: RBNode<E>? = null)
        : Node<RBNode<E>, E>(data, left, right){
        fun switchColor() : NodeColor{
            color = when (color) {
                NodeColor.RED -> NodeColor.BLACK
                else -> NodeColor.RED
            }
            return color
        }
    }
}

abstract class BinaryTree<N : Node<N, E>, E : Comparable<E>>() {

    abstract val rootNode: N

    abstract fun addNode(node : N)

    abstract fun removeNode() : N

    abstract class Node<N : Node<N, E>, E : Comparable<E>>(
        private val data: E,
        private val left: N? = null,
        private val right: N? = null) : Comparable<N> {

        fun isLeaf(): Boolean{
            return (left == null && right == null)
        }
        override fun compareTo(other: N): Int {
            return data.compareTo(other.data)
        }
    }
}
```

This way we ensure `RBTree` works with `RBNode` only. Please note `RBTree` is no longer a subtype of `BinaryTree<Node>`. Instead, it is a subtype of `BinaryTree<RBNode>`.

I removed `inner` from nodes as it seems this is not needed. If this is in fact required, then the case is a little more complicated, because nodes are implicitly typed by the tree as well.

Comment: If inner is needed, can we just remove the type parameters from Node and use the parameters given to BinaryTree for Node since it can now access them. For example would you then specify BinaryTree<N,E>.Node to use a typed node in a subclass? Does using the types from the outer class have drawbacks for subclasses? Obviously then all nodes in a tree are of the same type but that's okay because they have to be comparable anyway.